# Detect the position of the mouse press?

Tags: unity, c#

I am encountering an extremely absurd phenomenon. When I run this code on my smartphone **via Unity Remote** or even on the computer, it works as expected. But when I install the APK on the device and run it, the touch distance changes! Does this have something to do with resolution and Vector3.Distance?

```
    distance = Vector3.Distance (Input.mousePosition, button.position);

    Debug.Log (distance);

    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0) && distance > 55) {

        // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,

> [Input.GetMouseButtonDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) returns true during the frame the user pressed the given mouse button.

If you want to get mouse position on click then you can use `Input.mousePosition` in `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` is true, it will return mouse position in pixel coordinates.

```
Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        Debug.Log("Mouse position: " + Input.mousePosition);
}
```

**Edit:** It also works like a charm on touch devices. For single touch on touch devices you can use it without any doubt.

**Edit2:** As I mentioned that `Input.mousePosition` will give you pixel coordinates not world coordinates. Basically you are comparing Pixel point and World point, that'd obviously not gonna do what you want. But you can simply convert screen point to world point through [`ScreenToWorldPoint`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html). Like,

```
Vector3 mouseWorldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

distance = Vector3.Distance (mouseWorldPosition , button.position);
...
```

Comment: As I said, "I want to publish for smartphones, touch devices so I can't use `Input.mousePosition`" I already tested it and it doesn't work.

Comment: FYI, it is perfect for even touch devices. For single touch, it is perfect. You may have a look at [this game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dgamestudio.roadlinecar&hl=en). I did use `Input.GetMouseButton` and `Input.mousePosition` only and you can see, everything is working fine.

Comment: I substantially edited the question.  There's something wrong with the way `Vector3.Distance` measures distance.

Comment: @Dct4 This is totally a different question bro, well, check the edits

Comment: Your new edit still gets me the same problem. Review it, please :)

Comment: You need to put more code then